# Getting unauthorized error while trying to use google calendar api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

I am getting the following error while trying to use Google Calendar API in my application. I've tried debugging the following error but to no avail. I've been on it for the past week. I am using a devise Omniauth to log in using Google account to my application but after I try visiting `webhooks/callback` route it gives me the following error as well -

```
Signet::AuthorizationError in Webhooks::CalendarController#callback
Authorization failed. Server message:
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

My webhooks calendar controller looks like -

```
class Webhooks::CalendarController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  skip_after_action :verify_authorized

  def redirect
    client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)

    redirect_to client.authorization_uri.to_s, allow_other_host: true
  end

  def callback
    client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
    client.code = current_user.google_token
    response = client.fetch_access_token!
    session[:authorization] = response
    redirect_to calendar_url
  end

  def calendars
    client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
    client.update!(session[:authorization])

    service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
    service.authorization = client

    @calendar_list = service.list_calendar_lists
  end

  private

    def client_options
      {
        client_id: ENV.fetch("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID", ""),
        client_secret: ENV.fetch("GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET", ""),
        authorization_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        token_credential_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        scope: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::AUTH_CALENDAR_READONLY,
        redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback/"
      }
    end
end
```

I am setting the `google_token` while signing in using google like this -

```
user.google_token = request.query_parameters[:code]

user.save!
```

I have checked the permissions and stuff from the developer console and everything looks fine to me.

Comment: are you sure your not confusing a authorization code and a refresh token

Comment: I don't think so. Do you think me using the code which arrives from `request.query_parameters` might be the issue? I also tried using normal token which arrives in it but that again gives me the malformed error.

Comment: Kindly note I know almost nothing about ruby and even less about rails.  Have a look at this https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/main/samples/web/app.rb

Comment: do you have the power to tell me what comes back in response = client.fetch_access_token!

Comment: that line response = client.fetch_access_token! itself is throwing the error

Comment: the thing is the library should be doing all this for you.   but I dont know enough about rails.

Comment: Can you try changing the `token_credential_uri` value to `"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"`? You may also want to check https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-ruby/blob/main/spec/googleauth/signet_spec.rb

Comment: It still gives me the same error